# RIAK-CS Unable to create bucket using s3cmd - AccessDenied

Tags: riak, riak-cs

I have the following setup: riak 1.4.12, riakcs 1.5.3, stanchion 1.5.0

I am able to list bucket contents, and the authentication works (I get a response when listing or trying to remove a bucket, PUT a file) but get an AccessDenied error when trying to create a bucket.

I found this thread http://riak-users.197444.n3.nabble.com/RIAK-CS-Unable-to-create-bucket-using-s3cmd-AccessDenied-td4032375.html and tried adding signature_v2 = True to .s3cfg with no success, and I've also tried three versions of s3cmd (1.5.0, 1.5.0alpha, 1.0.1) I also tried creating a bucket using the python library boto, which also gives an access denied error.

I'm stumped :( any suggestions on where I should look next would be greatly appreciated! Not sure where there are logs for individual operations against Riak-cs - I've set lager log level to debug and wasn't able to see anything in the logs.

Thanks!
Ambert

Comment: If the key works for some operations but not others, see if you can get both sides to log the [StringToSign](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationStringToSign).  If both sides aren't building the string the same for a make bucket request, the authentication will fail.

Answer (score 3):

I posted the same question to [riak-users](http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com) mailing list, and [got an answer](http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2015-November/017823.html)!

In my case, I had to set the `admin.key` and `admin.secret` in `/etc/stanchion/stanchion.conf`.
After setting them, `s3cmd mb` succeeded.

Comment: I had the same issue. Also do not forget to make `stanchion restart` after setting `admin.key` and `admin.secret` values.